# Between with "and" or "or"

Tags: grammar

Which of these is grammatically correct:

"They had to choose between apples and oranges"

"They had to choose between apples or oranges"

Answer (score 15):

**The first sentence is correct.**

They had to choose between apples and oranges.

The second sentence should read:

They had to choose either apples or oranges.

**However since you are using "choose between", the correct conjunction is "and".**

Comment: Doesn't "choose between" mean (A or B) in the sense that you have to choose one. So if the first one is correct why shouldn't the second one? "Between" doesn't mean *both* (A and B). I think 'They had to choose between/either apples or oranges' is correct. And the conjunction "and" doesn't have to be with "choose between".